# Releasing with sort-of-circular dependencies between modules

Tags: java, maven

I have project A with child modules A1 and A2. A1 and A2 inherit their version from A. I also have project B which has its own version and depends upon A2. Finally, A1 depends upon B.

Without versioning concerns, this is not circular, but since A and B are the only things that are independently versioned, it effectively is. I can't release either with snapshot dependencies.

What to do? I've considered versioning A1 and A2 independently but perhaps there is a way that is easier to manage. A and B do not need to be released in lock-step.

Comment: Sounds like A2 should not be a child module of A or should be versioned independently.

Comment: Sounds like A1, A2 and B should all be submodules of A. Or A1 and A2 independent modules. The versioning problem is really telling you that you've a dependency organization problem.